# How to get whole string after first slash(/) using regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have been trying to get all the characters after the first slash using regexp in Tcl.

What is want is this:

```
abc/def/ghi
```

from the above string i want `def/ghi`.

I tried using the below command, but its only giving `ghi`

```
set abc [regexp {([^/]*)$} $string match]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the expression you want is `/(.*)$`, and then grab cluster group 1 as your result.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regexp for this simple case?

Just split the string at the first occurrence of `/`:

```
set str "abc/def/ghi"
string range $str [string first "/" $str]+1 end
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of getting the value is this:

```
regexp {/(.*)} $string -> match
```

The command will assign the string you want to `match`, and will (effectively) produce a boolean as a result indicating whether the RE matched at all (i.e., was there a `/` in the string), allowing you to detect if the input was bogus. No tail-anchoring of the RE is necessary; Tcl's RE engine will greedily consume from the first `/` to the end of the string.